# XML - XSLT group elements by count

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I need some help with XSLT,

I have the following input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<textContentList>
   <textContent>
      <value>LABEL1</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>LABEL2</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>LABEL3</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>LABEL4</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>LABEL5</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>FirstDATA1</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>FirstDATA2</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>FirstDATA3</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>FirstDATA4</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>FirstDATA5</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>SecondDATA1</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>SecondDATA2</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>SecondDATA3</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>SecondDATA4</value>
   </textContent>
   <textContent>
      <value>SecondDATA5</value>
   </textContent>
<textContentList>
```

And what I would like to do is to group each 5 consecutive `textContent` elements in new elements. Basically what I want to do is to create new `list` elements and each of these elements will have 5 consecutive `textContent` elements. Here is the output XML document I hope to get from the shown input document above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<textContentList>
   <list>
      <textContent>
         <value>LABEL1</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>LABEL2</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>LABEL3</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>LABEL4</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>LABEL5</value>
      </textContent>
   </list>
   <list>
      <textContent>
         <value>FirstDATA1</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
          <value>FirstDATA2</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>FirstDATA3</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>FirstDATA4</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>FirstDATA5</value>
      </textContent>
   </list>
   <list>
      <textContent>
         <value>SecondDATA1</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
          <value>SecondDATA2</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>SecondDATA3</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>SecondDATA4</value>
      </textContent>
      <textContent>
         <value>SecondDATA5</value>
      </textContent>
   </list>
<textContentList>
```

I figure that one way of doing this is using the count() function to count each 5 `textContent` elements and group them using the `<xsl:group-by>`, then pass to the next five `textContent` elements, but I don't know how to do it,

This is probably not very hard, but I don't really know how to do it with XSLT,

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Comment: Use positional grouping `<xsl:for-each-group select="textContent" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5"><list><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></list></xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: Exactly right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, Martin Honnen answered the question in a comment:

Use positional grouping

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="textContent" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
  <list>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </list>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```